# Horizontal form with 3 columns that stack when resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

On the web project I am currently working on we are using Bootstrap 3.  We are using the a form-horizontal layout with 3 columns- so the label appears left of the form input.  The basic markup looks something like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class=col-md-4">
            <!-- another input here -->
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- another input here -->
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Now the requirements I have just been given are for the form to have columns that keep their logical order and stack when the window is resized.

When the browser window is desktop sized it should look like this:

Column A field 1    Column B field 1    Column C field 1
Column A field 2    Column B field 2    Column C field 2
Column A field 3    Column B field 3        Column C field 3

But when the window is made smaller the form should resize and the columns stack like this:

Column A field 1
Column A field 2
Column A field 3

Column B field 1
Column B field 2
Column B field 3

Column C field 1
Column C field 2
Column C field 3

Is this possible with Boostrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jme11 to getting me on the right track.  I think I have figured this out - the following layout is exactly the look and behaviour that I need.  Hopefully this will help someone else out in the future.

```
         <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col A Input 1</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col A Input 1</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col A Input 2</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col A Input 2</div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col A Input 3</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col A Input 3</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col B Input 1</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col B Input 1</div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col B Input 2</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col B Input 2</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col B Input 3</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col B Input 3</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col C Input 1</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col C Input 1</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col C Input 2</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col C Input 2</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Col C Input 3</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="form-control-static">Col C Input 3</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cOBmjbNJ5dQGFAF5iTg0?p=preview)  (Make the preview pane larger to see the columns unstacked)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation for Bootstrap 3's grid system:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid There are pretty useful examples for a lot of use cases.

You should be good adding the class `col-xs-12` to your columns:

- `xs` for the smallest width (or `sm`, depending on the width you need)
- `12` for the number of columns to span, while 12 is the maximum/the full available width

This should make them stack on the small screen.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks - yes I have looked at that but I don't see an example that matches the behaviour I need - I think I have this figured out now though - see my latest post.  Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

You just don't want to overthink things.  This layout behaves exactly how you would what it to if you add all three of your inputs for each column grouping are wrapped inside a single col-md-4.  Each of those columns is now a single grid unit that will be collapsed at screen resolutions lower than 992px.  At 992px and up, each column will be next to each other.

Now you simply want to nest your inputs inside those columns.  **Remember** that when you nest col- classes in Bootstrap you have to add a row class or you'll get double padding.  So, to figure out when to have your labels on the left and when to have them above the input, you'll need to probably do a little trial and error.  In the example below, I found that for the length of the labels I was using, I needed to stack the labels for everything but the largest screens (1200px breakpoint in Bootstrap), otherwise the labels would wrap onto a second line.   You can add a responsive reset after each input if you would prefer to have the labels wrap, but I didn't like the look of it.

In the case of the example, the labels needed to be 4 grid columns wide at the lg breakpoint to not break onto a separate line.  That, of course, leaves 8 grid columns for each input.

Run the code snippet below, then hit the Full Page option, so you can resize your window and see how the form behaves at the sm/xs, md, and lg breakpoints respectively.

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  
input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="a1" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Col A Input 1</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="a1" placeholder="Col A Input 1" />
                </div>
                <label for="a2" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Col A Input 2</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="a2" placeholder="Col A Input 2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="b1" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Col B Input 1</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="b1" placeholder="Col B Input 1" />
                </div>
                <label for="b2" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Col B Input 2</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="b2" placeholder="Col A Input 2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="c1" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Col C Input 1</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="c1" placeholder="Col C Input 1" />
                </div>
                <label for="c2" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Col C Input 2</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" id="c2" placeholder="Col C Input 2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, I added `margin-bottom: 10px` to the input selector in the demo.  In practice, I would instead use a class at the form level so I could more specifically target just these inputs not all of my inputs universally, or wrap each separate label + input grouping in a div with a class and apply the margin to the bottom of that class.  Also, I would probably place it in a media query so that I could control the amount of margin applied at the different breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly the behaviour I was looking for.  The one big outstanding issue though is the spacing between the "rows" when the screen is larger.  There needs to be padding between the inputs on each column.  When the screen is larger these appear tight together.

Comment: Yes, that's also normal behavior for the col- classes in Bootstrap.  I would simply add a little margin-bottom to the inputs or you can add padding-bottom to your col- classes.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <!-- another input here -->
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <!-- another input here -->
         </div>
```

col-md-4 for medium screen scuh as laptop

col-lg-4 for Large screen

col-sm-4 for small screen like tablet

col-xs-12 for xtraa small screen, mobile

You can use this as your wish. I wrote here the code only the forms will display as stack in mobile version.